# How to access Flask web server from mobile device?

Tags: python-3.x, web, flask

I have FLask web development server running on my Mac @ `127.0.0.1:5000/`. Both my mac and my android device are connected to the same WLAN. I am unable to access my flask website by entering the IP address of my mac(`192.168.8.103:5000`) into the browser of my android device. But I can access the webpage from my apache server running on my Mac by entering `192.168.8.103` into the browser of my android device. Can I access the flask webserver from my mobile?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to run the app with your IPv4 address

`app.run(debug=True, host= '192.168.8.103')` assuming `192.168.8.103` is your `IPv4` if not, replace it with your `IPv4`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help !